# Upsampling Methods for Computed-Tomography

Tags: sampling, interpolation, 3d, 2d, reconstruction

I have two sets of data of given Field of view, one of them only covers a subset of the FOV of the other. I therefore want to upsample the one with the larger FOV to combine it with the other one.

So the question is: **In the context of X-ray computed tomography, where the x-rays projections are backprojected to obtain a 3D reconstruction of the object, what is the best upsampling method for the purposes mentioned above?**

Or to put it differently, **what are the features in an x-ray image that ideally we don't want to damage too much**... **is it the contrast, the sharpness of the edges, etc.** keep in mind, that as in many application of digital imaging, anti aliasing filters, Gaussian blurrings, etc. are performed on the images before them being processed for reconstruction purposes.

I know that each upsampling method has its merits, so considering the nature of the x-ray reconstruction methods, is there any way of deciding on one upsampling method based on the a-priori information of the object.

Comment: Well it's actually *filtered* backprojection, right? With a differentiation stage to enhance the sharpness of edges, which would otherwise be blurred by the reconstruction? http://www.impactscan.org/slides/eanm2002/sld014.htm  https://www.clear.rice.edu/elec431/projects96/DSP/filters.html So preserving edges would seem important.  And the projections are not anti-alias filtered before sampling, right?  So sinc interpolation is probably bad, like with any image processing, and would cause ringing at those edges?